# react native error: changing onviewableitemschanged on the fly is not supported

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I used the FlatList for creating the horizontal swipeable list. but when I want to change the card I saw this error. when I refresh the app everything is okay, just when I want to change the card (swipe) I have this error message.

```
         <FlatList 
            data={cards}
            renderItem={ ({item}) => <AccountCard cardInfo={item}/>}
            initialScrollIndex={0}
            horizontal={true}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            keyExtractor={ (item, index) => index.toString()}
            snapToInterval={ deviceWidth - wp('16.5%')}
            snapToAlignment={"start"}
            onViewableItemsChanged={({viewableItems, changed})=>{
                changed[0].isViewable && setSelectedSlide(changed[0].item.id);
            }}
            viewabilityConfig= {{viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 80}}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

If this error is simply appearing when you make actual changes to the code on an element that has a `Flatlist` with an `onViewableItemsChanged` prop, then that's not actually anything real going wrong. I believe this happens because:

- `onViewableItemsChanged` does not support the function changing during the component's lifecycle (which is why you generally need to wrap the function you pass to it in `useCallback` with an empty dependency array)
- In development, [React throws away the cache when you edit a component's file](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback#caveats).

So any time you make an edit, React empties the cache, and `Flatlist` thinks you've changed the `onViewableItemsChanged` handler during a component's lifecycle.

It's annoying, but you can just save the file again, without any changes, and the error will go away.

It's only if this error is appearing when taking an action *as a user* in your app that you need to make changes - and it probably means you need to wrap your `onViewableItemsChanged` handler in a `useCallback` **with an empty dependency array.**